# Angular : Kendo Scheduler time slots and events css

Tags: css, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-angular2, kendo-scheduler

**How can i set the height of the Kendo scheduler events and time slots ?**

I'm tried :

```
.k-scheduler-dayview .k-scheduler-table td,
.k-scheduler-weekview .k-scheduler-table td,
.k-scheduler-table td{
    height: 50px !important;
}
```

or

```
<kendo-scheduler-week-view eventHeight="50px">
</kendo-scheduler-week-view>
```

or

```
<kendo-scheduler eventHeight="50px">
     //...some code
</kendo-scheduler>
```

..but it's still not working.

> *I'm using Angular 8, not jQuery*

Thank you in advance !

Comment: How much height it is taking right now is it more than 50 or less then 50

Comment: @HitechHitesh 25px, according to Google Chrome Developers Tool

Answer (score 0):

You can use the eventClass property of the SchedulerComponent.

See this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kqsgvs)